# how can I remove the black screen comes in my game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

[image]

In the following image, there is a transparent image, but the thing is that I have to remove the black screen, but not I remove this black screen , I set the layer opacity to zero, but not get the output.???

HOw Can I remove that black image;

Comment: Do you have your transparent image on a new CCLayer?

Comment: is your 'game over' layer added as a child to the game scene or is it on a separate CCScene from the layer that appears behind?

Answer (score 2):

We need to know how you create that image.

If you are using and UIImageView set the background color to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a UIView instance set background color to clear color like this

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```